# Is there a way to get ssid while location is turned off although correct permissions are given in latest android

Tags: java, android

While on wifi although precise location permission given to app (confirmed from settings), I was unable to get ssid while location service is turned off in latest android.

Also manifest permissions looks like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Thanks.